# Why won't my if/else statement work? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to code a script to test whether a user-inputted number is prime or not. I'm coding several different primality tests, but one in particular is giving me a hard time.

```
function isPrimeSix() {
    var numberPrimeSix = document.getElementById("primeSixInput").value;
    var loopCount = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < Math.floor((numberPrimeSix / 6) + 1) + 1; i++)
    {
        if (numberPrimeSix === (6 * i) + 1)
        {
            //Irrelevant code here//
        }
        else if (numberPrimeSix === (6 * i) - 1)
        {
            //More irrelevant code//
        }
        else
        {
            loopCount++
        }
    };
    if (numberPrimeSix === 2 || numberPrimeSix === 3 || numberPrimeSix === 5 || numberPrimeSix === 7)
    {
        alert(numberPrimeSix + " is prime.");
    }
    else if (prime === false || loopCount === Math.floor((numberPrimeSix / 6) + 1))
    {
        alert(numberPrimeSix + " is not prime.");
    }
    else if (prime === true)
    {
        alert(numberPrimeSix + " is prime.");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Error");
    };
}
```

Every time the `for` loop goes around, the embedded `if` statement will not evaluate, even if for that particular value of `i` one of the statements is true. Regardless of what number is assigned to `numberPrimeSix`, the script will always go to the `else` section of the loop, meaning that an alert will pop up telling me that the number is not prime (because the value of `loopCount` is equal to the value defined by the last `if` statement).

Can anyone tell me why this is? I hope this makes sense, and if the 'irrelevant code' is needed I'll provide it. Thanks!

Comment: a string will never be exactly equal (===) to a number. (finding this dupe will be near impossible...)

Comment: How do you know that that's what it's doing? The JavaScript runtime doesn't just randomly choose not to execute statements. Have you stepped through the code in a debugger?

Comment: To expand on @KevinB s comment, try doing `numberPrimeSix = parseInt(numberPrimeSix, 10);`

Comment: further reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons you should definitely continue to use `===` since it is faster and you're in a loop, however, that means you'll need to do the type conversion before the loop.

Comment: Kevin B was right, I changed all the `===` to `==` and it works fine. I'm very new to this language and had no idea there were different ways to say 'equal to'. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string will never be exactly equal (`===`) to a number. In JavaScript, if you use `==`, the operands will be converted to be the same type before comparing. If you instead use `===`, that step will be skipped and instead they will be tested for strict equality, meaning same type and value, not just same value.

You have two options. Replace `===` with `==`, or, convert the value before the loop and continue using strict equal. [It will be much faster](http://jsperf.com/comparison-of-comparisons) to convert the value before the loop so that you're not converting it over and over with each iteration.

```
var numberPrimeSix = parseInt(document.getElementById("primeSixInput").value, 10);
```

---

more reading: [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: oh, jsperf is down. maybe that link will work in the future.